# Android dates persisting in a array

Tags: android, date, calendar

I Want to store  ten date(in range before and after time interval) in a array

ex:-`Today's date is 03-02-2016;`

my expected array `{01-02-2016,02-02-2016,03-02-2016,04-02-2016,05-02-2016,06-02-2016,07-02-2016,08-02-2016,09-02-2016,10-02-2016}.`

Array type may be string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                String date1 = sdf1.format(calendar.getTime());
                System.out.println(date1);
            }
        } else {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +1);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
            System.out.println(date);
            dateinterval.add(date);
        }
    }
```

Finally I got the answer